Solving for expectation using iteration in a implicit function
For a implicit function $V(k,l)$, taking $l$ as given and $k$ to be the only variable, $k$ is sampling from an unknown distribution and $\mathbb{E}k = \bar{K}$. Using Taylor expansion on $V(k,l)$ around the expectation $\bar{K}$, it gives that
$V(k,l) = V(\bar{K},l) + V_k(\bar{K},l)(k - \bar{K})$
where we ignore the higher order terms. Ideally, we now can find $\bar{K}$ with this expression by
$\bar{K} = k - (V(k,l) - V(\bar{K},l)) / (V_k(\bar{K},l))$
I know that the solving process can be done by iteration
$K_{n+1} = k - \frac{V(k, l) - V(K_n, l)}{V_k(K_n, l)}$
until $\|K_{n+1} - K_{n}\|<\epsilon$, where the chosen variable $k$ is fixed.
My questions:
(1) does it work if $k$ is away from the expectation I try to solve? I know it would take a long time or even may fail to converge if $k$ is away from $\bar{K}$.
(2) if I adjust $k$ according to $K_n$ at the beginning of each iteration, like randomly pick a value in the neighbourhood of $K_n$, does this affects the result?

In your iteration, which values are given? Since $k,l$ do not appear on the left side, are you given $k,l$? Multiple pairs of values $k,l$?
